# Do blocks in HDFS have byte-offset information stored in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, block, hdfs, offset, hadoop2

Consider I have a single File which is `300MB`. The `block` size is `128MB`.
So the input file is divided into the following chunks and placed in HDFS.

```
Block1: 128MB
Block2: 128MB
Block3: 64MB.
```

Now Does each block's data has `byte offset` information contained in it.
That is, do the blocks have the following `offset` information?

```
Block1: 0-128MB of File
Block2  129-256MB of File
Block3: 257MB-64MB of file
```

If so, how can I get the byte-offset information for Block2 (That is it starts at 129MB) in Hadoop.
This is for understanding purposes only. Any hadoop command-line tools to get this kind of meta data about the blocks?

**EDIT**

If the byte-offset info is not present, a mapper performing its map job on a block will start consuming lines from the beginning. If the offset information is present, the mapper will skip till it finds the next EOL and then starts processing the records.
So I guess byte offset information is present inside the blocks.

Comment: No idea myself, but I'd start by writing a small script that generates a 300mb file.

Comment: @admdrew: I am not concerned about getting a 300MB file. but more on the internals of how block meta-data is stored (within the block)

Comment: Agreed. Bookmarked; I hope someone answers!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I might be wrong on this one I have not read that much of the HDFS source code.

Basically, datanodes manage blocks which are just large blobs to them. They know the block id but that its. The namenode knows everything, especially the mapping between a file path and all the block ids of this file and where each block is stored. Each block id can be stored in one or more locations depending of its replication settings.

I don't think you will find public API to get the information you want from a block id because HDFS does not need to do the mapping this way. On the opposite you can easily know the blocks and their locations of a file. You can try explore the [source code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/tree/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server), especially the blockmanager package.

If you want to learn more, [this article about the HDFS architecture](http://www.aosabook.org/en/hdfs.html) could be a good start.

Comment: I am sorry, but this does not answer the question in any sense. I know how mapping of blocks happens between NameNode and Datanodes. But the question here has more to do with byte-offset info in blocks. If such information is not present, a mapper performing its map job on a block will start consuming lines from the beginning. If the offset information is present, the mapper skips till it finds the next EOL and then starts processing the records.

Comment: If you want to know how DFSInputStream does its job we can read the source code. In ctor you will see that `dfsclient.getLocatedBlock` is invoked to get a `LocatedBlocks`. Then, when you reach the end of a block (or seek outside of the block) `blockEnd` is set to -1 which will trigger a call to `seekToBlockSource` which will call `LocatedBlocks.findBlock`. A `LocatedBlock` has a size and an offset, they are sorted a binary search is done to find the right block. I believe that to get good answers you have to clearly define the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `hdfs  fsck /path/to/file -files -blocks` to get the list of blocks.

A [`Block`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/990db99601b28e2a292a0c1322ffe4f334e90c47/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocol/Block.java) does not contain offset info, only length. But you can use [`LocatedBlocks`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/990db99601b28e2a292a0c1322ffe4f334e90c47/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocol/LocatedBlocks.java) to get all blocks of a file and from this you can easily reconstruct each block what offset it starts at.

Comment: can you see my edit above in the question. The offset info for the block should be present somewhere. Otherwise a record boundary will not be properly established.

Comment: records are a mapred concept. Blocks are an HDFS concept, not related to mapred. blocks do not contain offsets, but offsets can be passed to the inputformat.

Comment: each block typically corresponds to inputSplit, which are just logical partitions. In which case, for the inputSplit to know which block it is proccessing, it must know the byte-offset from sowmehow correct?

Comment: The InputFormat defines the splits. A `FileSplit` has a path, an offset and a length. A mapper get a FileSplit, it opens an inputstream on a path then seek to the offset. If you want to know how the seek is done see my previous comment. It's open source, take the time to browse the sources.

Comment: @brainstorm: don't mix blocks and splits so easily. Consider that mapred can run on top of a different FS, like the local FS or on top of wasb, and many more that have no blocks. Your questions are really about the mapred input, not about HDFS blocks.